# How can I add a 2nd macro in excel in a existing worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am updating a sales tool in excel.  It currently has 1 small macro that will automatically update when a user inputs or selects a new status by adding a time stamp.

I want to add another macro on the same sheet but in a different range of cells.  This would update when a sale is made when the user updates to SOLD to also have a new time stamp.  I tried creating a new variable and repeated the If / then statement with new range and new variables but it did not work.

The first If /Then works without issue the `myTimeRange`, but the 2nd If/then `mySoldRange` is not.
Here is the code snip

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range
Dim mySoldRange As Range
Dim mySoldTimeRange As Range
Dim mySoldUpdatedRange As Range

Set myTableRange = Range("A2:E300")
Set mySoldRange = Range("H2:K300")


If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRange = Range("F" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("G" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
    
    myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    
End If

If Intersect(Target, mySoldRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set mySoldTimeRange = Range("H" & Target.Row)
Set mySoldUpdatedRange = Range("K" & Target.Row)

If mySoldTimeRange.Value = "" Then
    
    mySoldTimeRange.Value = Now
End If
myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

mySoldUpdatedTimeRange.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> `If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

You can't use `Exit Sub` here if you want to test if `Target` intersects another range.

Change instead to:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("F" & Target.Row)
    Set myUpdatedRange = Range("G" & Target.Row)

    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    End If    
End If
```

and similarly (though not technically necessary, but to be consistent):

```
If Not Intersect(Target, mySoldRange) Is Nothing Then
   ...
End If
```

Comment: I see . Thanks for your assistance.  I will add that and try it out .